# Set column name ddply

Tags: r, plyr

How to set the column name of the summarized data in

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data,.(col1,col2),nrow)
```

like in

```
ddply(data,.(col1,col2),function(x) data.frame(number=nrow(x)))
```

Comment: Did you look at the very first example of `?ddply`?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with your *like in* example?

Comment: @Henrik, if you mean `ddply(dfx, .(group, sex), summarize,
 mean = round(mean(age), 2),
 sd = round(sd(age), 2))` then I do, but it looks so different from the explanation of the function declaration that I cant map the third and fourth parameter.

Comment: I agree with Klaus here that the documentation structure could be improved. If you don't know about `summarize` and so on, it can be a bit confusing what's going on and what needs to be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `summarize` (or `mutate` or `transform`, depending on what you want to do).

A small example:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
                   col2 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1),
                   z = rnorm(6))
ddply(data,.(col1,col2), summarize, 
      number = length(z), newcol = mean(z))
#   col1 col2 number     newcol
# 1    1    1      1 -0.6264538
# 2    2    2      2 -0.3259926
# 3    3    1      1  1.5952808
# 4    3    2      1  0.3295078
# 5    4    1      1 -0.8204684
```

Comment: you can also use the grouping variables, hence: `length(col1)`.