# Performing multiple functions (mean, sd, etc.) on all numeric columns in a dataframe with ddply()

Tags: r, plyr

I am not quite an R novice, but I'm trying to teach myself how to use plyr, since in many cases it's much faster than writing endless for loops! However, I've run into a problem that I can't seem to find an answer for here, in the documentation for plyr, or anywhere else-- at least, not as I'm able to identify them as such. I won't rule out that they're there and I'm just not recognizing them!

I have a dataset of many columns, and I'm looking for a way to perform multiple functions on all of the columns without having to copy the code and just change a single argument. I've successfully found and used numcolwise(sd) to get the standard deviation of every numeric column, which was my first big hurdle. I was not about to type the names of every column in my dataset! Example code with the 'iris' dataset, because my dataset is obnoxious:

```
n<-ddply(iris,"Species",numcolwise(sd)) #Calculate the sd for all numeric columns in the dataset
```

and I get this:

```
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa    0.3524897   0.3790644    0.1736640   0.1053856
2 versicolor    0.5161711   0.3137983    0.4699110   0.1977527
3  virginica    0.6358796   0.3224966    0.5518947   0.2746501
```

And that totally works and does what I wanted. I can even make the column names indicate that they're standard deviation:

```
colnames(n)[2:5]<-paste(colnames(s)[2:5],".sd",sep="") #append .sd to all column names
```

And that's all great, and I definitely couldn't do that before yesterday.

Okay, so here's where my problem comes in. I'm trying to be as efficient as possible, and I would rather not just copy and rerun the ddply function and colnames function multiple times to end up with a dataframe for sd, another dataframe for mean, and yet another for se. In addition, assuming I could find a way to supply multiple functions as arguments for numcolwise(), I don't know what I would do about the column names.

I know there are ways to calculate mean, sd, and whatever else using summarize(), and that when you do that, you can specify the names of columns (see [Set column name ddply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442555/set-column-name-ddply)). But I can't figure out how, or if, the method used there with summarize can be used with numcolwise() and multiple function arguments (sd, mean, ...) to get something like this:

```
     Species Sepal.Length.sd Sepal.Width.sd Petal.Length.sd Petal.Width.sd Sepal.Length.mean Sepal.Width.mean Petal.Length.mean Petal.Width.mean
1     setosa       0.3524897      0.3790644       0.1736640      0.1053856             5.006            3.428             1.462            0.246
2 versicolor       0.5161711      0.3137983       0.4699110      0.1977527             5.936            2.770             4.260            1.326
3  virginica       0.6358796      0.3224966       0.5518947      0.2746501             6.588            2.974             5.552            2.026
```

Note: I know I could do this using a sort of "brute force" method using join(), because I've done that with other datasets that I needed to smush together. But that seems somewhat inelegant and repetitive, and I'm eventually going to have an even *larger* dataset to do this with, because right now I'm just working with my pilot data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It´s pretty straightforward with `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean,sd))
```

Comment: See, I just knew it'd be something gloriously simple that I'd somehow missed with every google search I've tried. Thank you so much!

Comment: since an update of dplyr that last function is now called `summarise_all()`

Comment: Is there a way to do this where only numeric columns are summarized?

Comment: @milo `summarize_if(is.numeric, funs(mean, sd))`